# i couldn't understand the types CvMat, mat and IplImage?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I'm new to the Opencv.I have started reading the official documentation, i couldn't understand the  types  CvMat, mat and IplImage ? 
thank you for your help.

Comment: What don't you understand in particular? Reread your question thoroughly, how should one know what you want to know/don't understand in particular?!? Do you wan't us to repeat the whole documentation including personal, explanatory comments here, really?

Comment: javacv is a 3rd party java wrapper around opencv's old, now deprecated c-api bindings. you might be much better off using opencv's own java wrappers (which are not using those types at all)

Comment: I will refer you to this - https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Answer (score 2):

Forget [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/), it was a JavaCV binding to OpenCV created by Google but they no longer maintain it. OpenCV now has its own [official Java binding](http://docs.opencv.org/java/). JavaCV now seems to be part of [bytedeco](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/README.md).

Note that OpenCV's Java API only has a [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html), IplImage and CvMat are relics of the C API (which is basis of JavaCV) which [has been deprecated in favor of the C++ API](http://www.slideshare.net/EugeneKhvedchenya/opencv-30-latest-news-and-the-roadmap). Mat is a primary data-structure of the C++ API, hence the Java API.

In Summary, do not use JavaCV, and if you write C++, do not create new code that uses CvMat or IplImage.